# how to view inside of .odb database file without connecting to open office?

Tags: c#, database

I want to know if it is possible to view inside of odb database file without connecting to OpenOffice in c#?i want to just view rows of table not add row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenOffice odb file format is basically a zip archive, which contains several folders holding data and metadata in xml format.

So probably you can unpack odb either using [ZipFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) from .net 4.5,
or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library, and then process xml files according to [OpenOffice file format](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office) specifications.

Or use some already available libraries for .net ([OpenOffice and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390006/openoffice-and-net))

Comment: can using hsql embeded be solution for this problem?

Comment: It is possible to view raw data contents of odb file. To query data you need to parse xml files. It is possible, but difficult, as there is very little support for .net to work with openoffice documents.

Comment: I just wan to to view data inside of odb files for this best way unzip(you said) or hsql?